# Catalog Page Crashes On Backend in Configuration

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, magento2.4.1, exception-error

After logging into backend and navigating to Stores > Configuration > Catalog, Site crashes and shows this error, also the search on the site shows same error.[image: Same error on catalog and catalog search]

Please note that Catalog Search on the index management shows "Reindex Required", which I have tried to resolve through multiple ways but the case remains same.

PS: magento version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded to the latest magento version please verify 2.4. changelog:

"The MySQL search engine has been removed from Magento 2.4.0 and replaced as the default search engine with Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch provides superior search capabilities as well as catalog performance optimizations. All merchants must have Elasticsearch to install and deploy Magento 2.4.0."

There are chances within your search engine Mysql must be selected. You will have to set it to Elastic search and also install elastic search on the server.

1. Login into Magento Admin
2. goto system configuration -> Catalog Search
3. check the search engine
   update that to elasticseatch7 configure the host & ports then save

Further, follow these commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Also, make sure the Elastic search server version is 7.

There may be also the case ElasticSearch module is de-activated it should be reactivated. ElasticSearch is required to run Magento 2.4.

Comment: By going to configuration -> Catalog Search is showing the same error which I have added the screenshot above where I have also explained this. that's why I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Try checking the current search engine by executing below command :
bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine if its mysql you can update it by executing the below query :
UPDATE core_config_data set value = 'elasticsearch7' where path='catalog/search/engine';